# How to copy a struct that contains String fields

Tags: rust, struct, types, serde

I have a `user` struct containing String fields:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct User {
    pub _id: ObjectId,
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
}
```

I want to have another struct with less fields:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct SimplerUser {
    pub _id: ObjectId,
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
}
```

Ideally, I would like to have:

```rust
impl User {
    pub fn sanitize(&self) -> SimplerUser {
        SimplerUser {
            _id: self._id,
            name: self.name,
            email: self.email
        }
    }
}
```

But even with adding Copy in the derive of struct User, it is not compiling.
Any idea of a simple solution?

Comment: Where does the type `ObjectId` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions. The simple one is just to clone the Strings.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct User {
    pub _id: ObjectId,
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct SimplerUser {
    pub _id: ObjectId,
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
}

impl User {
    pub fn sanitize(&self) -> SimplerUser {
        SimplerUser {
            _id: self._id,  // Does this need .clone() too? is ObjectId: Copy?
            name: self.name.clone(),
            email: self.email.clone(),
        }
    }
}

// or perhaps prefer `impl From<User> for SimplerUser` instead
```

However if you know your SimplerUser will always be outlived by your User, you can define it with a lifetime and use `&str` instead.

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct SimplerUser<'a> {
    pub _id: ObjectId,
    pub name: &'a str,
    pub email: &'a str,
}

impl<'a, 'b> From<&'b User> for SimplerUser<'a>
where
    'b: 'a  // where User outlives SimplerUser
{
    fn from(value: &'b User) -> Self {
        Self {
            _id: value._id,
            name: value.name.as_str(),
            email: value.email.as_str(),
        }
    }
}

impl User {
    pub fn sanitize(&self) -> SimplerUser {
        self.into()
    }
}
```

The difference is that in the former case, SimplerUser owns its data (the name and email) and therefore you'll be copying those strings in memory. The latter case requires that the User object stays valid so the owned Strings are not cleaned up while the SimplerUser merely references those strings, avoiding the copied memory.